# Translation of “version control system”

Tags: traduction, informatique, terminologie

I am writing my CV in French (because I am in Marseille).

I want to include my knowledge of "*version control systems*" but is the equivalent term in French "*contrôle de version*" correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In french, instead of using "contrôle de version", I would use "Gestion de version". So for a "version control system" I would use "système de gestion de versions" or even "logiciel de gestion de versions".

"Gestion de version" seems to be the expression widely used, as a Google search for "gestion de version" and "contrôle de versions" both return the same results which points to the expression "gestion de version".

And for the complete expressions, "logiciel de gestion de versions" seems to be the most common one. "logiciel de gestion de versions" also seems to be the expression [that Wikipedia uses](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logiciel_de_gestion_de_versions) (even though that may not be the most official source). I'm still looking for an official source but haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 5):

In computer and software industry we use "gestion de configuration" even if I admit that "gestion de version" is better. It appears in a great lot of French resumes, though.

Comment: Gestion de configuration?! Je n'ai jamais entendu ce terme. Je ne vois pas trop le lien entre configuration et version en parlant d'un fichier de code.

Comment: @HugoDozois Le terme « [gestion de configuration](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestion_de_configuration) » traduit l'expression anglaise « [configuration management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management) ». C'est un peu plus large — les systèmes de contrôle de version sont un moyen d'assurer la gestion de configuration.

Comment: Je sais bien que le terme "configuration" n'est pas approprié mais il est pourtant couramment utilisé.